# Can't start HSQLDB (java.net.BindException: Address already in use)

Tags: java, exception, hsqldb

```
~~~~~@debian:~/Workspace/SEPM1$ java -cp lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server -database.0 mydb -dbname.0 SEPM1
[Server@46f5c8fb]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
[Server@46f5c8fb]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
[Server@46f5c8fb]: Startup sequence initiated from main() method
[Server@46f5c8fb]: Loaded properties from [/home/~~~~~/Workspace/SEPM1/server.properties]
[Server@46f5c8fb]: Initiating startup sequence...
[Server@46f5c8fb]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @46f5c8fb,5,main]]: run()/openServerSocket(): 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
    at org.hsqldb.server.HsqlSocketFactory.createServerSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.server.Server.openServerSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.server.Server.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.server.Server.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.server.Server$ServerThread.run(Unknown Source)
[Server@46f5c8fb]: Initiating shutdown sequence...
[Server@46f5c8fb]: Shutdown sequence completed in 5 ms.
[Server@46f5c8fb]: 2012-03-27 11:06:32.569 SHUTDOWN : System.exit() is called next
~~~~~@debian:~/Workspace/SEPM1$ netstat
```

I was working in eclipse on university project. We were required to use hsqldb, and while trying to start it up I get an error stating the address is in use.

I'm not really sure how to fix this. I googled it but all related topics I could find were about a specific programs, so that was a dead end. Suggestions?

Comment: The error is previous obvious, isn't? You have another program running that is using the same port. Maybe even a HSQLDB instance that you forgot to shutdown properly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Most likely, as I ran it before without problems. But I did shut it down properly as I recall. I can't seem to find hsqldb in processes in order to kill it. Already killed all java, but that didn't work

Comment: Try 'netstat -n' and look, which ports are bound.

Comment: @ckuetbach Found it and stopped it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a different port for the server by adding a `--port nnnn` commmand line argument. The same port must be used on the client, for example `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:1234/SEPM1`.

See the Guide: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/listeners-chapt.html

Comment: That did it thank you. However, the problem seems to be caused by a incorrect closing of hsqldb...